# How to build and run a Ruby command-line tool found on github?

Tags: ruby

Hi cloned a simple app ( https://github.com/cfx/twix) on github that allows me to send Twitter messages from the console, but I'm not sure how to run it.

I now have a folder in my users/name director called Twix. Inside twix, I have these folders created by the app.

```
README      Rakefile    bin     lib     test
```

The readme doesn't provide a lot of instruction to get things started. It just tells you what to do after the program's running (see below).

Questions: What command do I use to get this started? What folder do I need to be in?

The README

```
Twix 0.0.1


Simple twitter client for console


Keys:

q - quit
t - write new message

If you want to post your twit, finish you message with !SEND
If you want abort and back to your feed, finish your message with !EXIT

new features soon
```

Comment: Someone felt your question is off-topic, but I don't really understand why. This may very well be a case of elitism, but don't worry, not everyone here is like that.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter or the close-requester, but generally questions here should pertain to code, not how to run something on the command line.

Comment: @MarkThomas does that mean we should vote to transfer it to ServerFault or SuperUser?

Comment: @Benoit That was my first thought based on the question title, but since it really is about building and installing a gem to get access to its command-line executable, it's in fuzzy territory. I'm fine with keeping it here (though maybe the question title should be edited).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This program is packaged as a gem. The following command will install the gem (run it in the `Twix` directory):

```
rake package && gem install pkg/twix-0.0.1.gem
```

You can now run the program from anywhere with the `twix` command.

**Edit**

The first thing I saw in the repository was the `Rakefile`, meaning there were some rake tasks defined. When you find yourself in this case, running `rake -T` is your best bet as it will show you the rake tasks available. Its output was the following:

```
(in /home/benoit/code/clones/twix)
rake clobber_package  # Remove package products
rake gem              # Build the gem file twix-0.0.1.gem
rake package          # Build all the packages
rake repackage        # Force a rebuild of the package files
```

I picked the command that would be the most likely to build the gem: the `package` one. I guess the `gem` task would have worked as well.

Running `rake package` gave me the following output:

```
(in /home/benoit/code/clones/twix)
mkdir -p pkg
WARNING:  no homepage specified
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: twix
  Version: 0.0.1
  File: twix-0.0.1.gem
mv twix-0.0.1.gem pkg/twix-0.0.1.gem
```

All that was left was to install the `pkg/twix-0.0.1.gem` created by the previous command:

```
gem install pkg/twix-0.0.1.gem
```

There's another case you could have encountered: the presence of a `twix.gemspec` in the root directory of the application. In this case, running:

```
gem build twix.gemspec
```

would have built the gem, the installation step remains the same.

Comment: Thanks very much. I know what rake does from using rails, but if you have time can you explain "package" and why you also did "pkg/twix"? Are those commands I would use to install and run any gem?

Comment: @PunkOnALark edited my answer, tell me if something isn't clear.

Comment: @Mischa no problem. I felt this deserved a detailed answer because you don't have to be a ruby dev to hit this problem, you could be a sysadmin or a user trying to install an application.

Answer (score 0):

```
ruby ./bin/twix
```

or

```
ruby -I lib ./bin/twix
```